# Responsive Website For Mobile Device

Tags: html, css

I'm using this css code for mobile device. In `chrome` it looks ok, but in `FireFox` this code isn't running, so my website doesn't change. What should i do?

```
@media (min-width: 220px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
      .nav a {
      color: #5a5a5a;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 14px 10px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .nav ul.pull-left{
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-left: 80px;
      } 
    .nav ul.pull-right{
      padding-top: 30px;
    }   
    .nav li {
      display: inline;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }   
    .nav-account{
    background-color: #204056;
    }
        .nav-account a {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding: 14px 10px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }   
    .nav-account ul.pull-right{
      padding-top: 10px;
    }   
    .nav-account li {
      display: inline;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .site-header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 50vh;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      background: url(../images/novotel.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: To be clear - does it work in Chrome, Firefox or neither? And are you working on a screen between 220px and 480px wide?

Comment: Can you post the HTML to?

Comment: im using that css for iphone screen. When im using chrome, my code can responsive but when im using mozilla, my website is can't be responsive and not change. Am my code (@media screen) is wrong?

Comment: @DavidWinalda can you post your html too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the media type after "@media".

Try @media all and (min-width: 220px) and (max-width: 480px) {

...

}

Comment: or @media screen and (min-width: 220px) and (max-width: 480px) {

...

}